# Hibernate trace values of statement parameters except blobs

Tags: java, hibernate, logging

To trace parameter values of hibernate SQL statements, a common log4j parametrization looks like that:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL">
  <level value="debug" />
</logger>
<logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder">
  <level value="trace" />
</logger>
```

This yields log outputs like that:

```
2019-01-10 00:10:29,349 [main] DEBUG  SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:92) - select land0_.fk_land as fk_land1_24_0_ from land land0_ where land0_.fk_land=?
2019-01-10 00:10:29,349 [main] TRACE  BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:65) - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [27]
```

This is very useful to analyze how the application path was executed at runtime.

The problem is, that `BasicBinder` also logs the whole string representation of values of LOB parameters (like `byte[]`) which is very unuseful:

```
2019-01-07 13:28:45,466 [wwsservices-catalina-exec-10] TRACE   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: binding parameter [2] as [BLOB] - [[37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 52, ...
```

The string representation of the whole blob is printed to the log file which is very annoying to me.

**Is there a way to suppress / shorten log output of LOB values in Hibernate or log4j while still displaying values of other statement parameters?**

Is there a possibility to set maximum log statement size in log4j?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has been an issue [HHH-11097](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11097)  fixed for Hibernate 5.2.3 which should also solve your problem:

In [this commit](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/c7c9e421454fd6c5c4ac426f39dffe9440a8ba37), the `BlobTypeDescriptor`(and others) gets an override for `extractLoggableRepresentation`:

```
@Override
public String extractLoggableRepresentation(Blob value) {
    return value == null ? "null" : "BLOB{...}";
}
```

The default implementation (causing your issue) now overridden looks like this:

```
@Override
public String extractLoggableRepresentation(T value) {
    return (value == null) ? "null" : value.toString();
}
```

This should remove those giant lines from your log.

If you are using a recent version of hibernate, you are likely using materialized blobs / primitive byte arrays (`byte[]`). The type descriptor responsible for this is [PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/e5dc635a52362f69b69acb8d5b166b69b165dbbd/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/java/PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.java#L62) which madly implements the `extractLoggableRepresentation` method like this:

```
@Override
public String extractLoggableRepresentation(byte[] value) {
    return (value == null) ? super.extractLoggableRepresentation( null ) : Arrays.toString( value );
}
```

The only solutions I see in this case are

- **[Report this as a bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HHH/issues)**
- Prevent usage of materialized blobs.
- **Use a workaround by implementing a custom `UserType`**:

The custom `UserType` must implement the `nullSafeSet` and pass a custom `JavaTypeDescriptor` to the binder which does the binding and logging:

```
@Override
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index,
        final SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

    // Simply do what 
    // org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement, Object, int, WrapperOptions)
    // does, but using a custom descriptor.

    session.remapSqlTypeDescriptor(MaterializedBlobType.INSTANCE.getSqlTypeDescriptor())
            .getBinder(CustomPrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE)
            .bind(st, (byte[]) value, index, session);
}
```

The custom `JavaTypeDescriptor` simply extends the `PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor` and overrides the problematic `extractLoggableRepresentation` method:

```
public class CustomPrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor extends PrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor {
    public static final CustomPrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor INSTANCE = new CustomPrimitiveByteArrayTypeDescriptor();

    @Override
    public String extractLoggableRepresentation(byte[] value) {
        if (null == value) {
            return super.extractLoggableRepresentation(value);
        } else {
            return "byte[" + value.length + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, @Selaron. How do I use the UserType? Just use it as field type in the entity? Can you please provide a sample?

Comment: @andy You can either register the `UserType` under a custom name, or map the property to the fully qualified class name: `@Type( type = "your.custom.ByteArrayType" )`. See the [Hibernate Custom Type chapter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type-UserType) for details.

Comment: which type does the custom `UserType` extend?

Comment: It implements the interface `org.hibernate.usertype.UserType`. It just manages how to receive your `byte[]` array from a SQL ResultSet or bind it as parameter to a PreparedStatement.

Comment: I think most useful hint in this answer is: _Use current Hibernate version_

Comment: @andy did that solve it? Which version where you using?

Comment: in the past we used 4.2.0. Now I use 5.3.7.

Comment: Using a custom type does not work if you want to use Converters.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I was having this problem today and found a way to log all types normally while avoiding the blob type using log4j2 filters, specifically a RegexFilter

```
 <AsyncLogger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="trace" additivity="false">
    <RegexFilter regex=".*[BLOB].*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="File" />
 </AsyncLogger>
```

Maybe this will be usefull to someone.

Comment: when I created the question, I was using log4j. But in the meantime we are using log4j2. So this is also a possible solution. Thank you.